# A $C^2$ function such that $\left \| \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u \partial v}(x) \right \| \leq \left \| u \right \|\left \| v \right \|$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Suppose $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is an open and convex set, $f:U  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is $C^2$ such that $0 \in U$,  $f(0)=0$.
>
> Prove that $$\left \| \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u \,\partial v}(x) \right \| \leq \left \| u \right \|\left \|  v \right \| \text{ for all }x \in U \text{ and } u,v\in \mathbb{R}^{m} $$.

I know that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(x)= \nabla f(x) \cdot u$ .

Now,   if I take the second directional derivative I get confuse and dont really see what the proper notation is.

Comment: I could not find this problem in the book you mentioned.

Comment: Maybe it's somewhere else, thats what he told me.

Answer (score 1):

Just note that $\nabla f(x) \cdot u$ is still a function of $x$, given by 
$$
\nabla f(x) \cdot u = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} u_1 + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} u_2
$$

So now you must compute

$$
\nabla(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} u_1 + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} u_2)\cdot v = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1^2}u_1 v_1 + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2} u_2 v_1 +\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_2 \partial x_1}u_1 v_2 + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_2^2}u_2 v_2  $$

However, regarding the result, the data seems insufficient.

Comment: I forgot to add $f'(0)=0$ but since $f(0)=0$. Also i think this  exercise who my prof gave isn't the correct translation (this exercise is from Lima Analisis Vol 2 Book). This notation was my main problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Note that$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_m}\\
 \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_1}& \cdots & \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_m}
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
u_1\\
 \vdots \\
u_m
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\sum_k\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_k}u_k\\
 \vdots \\
\sum_k\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_k}u_k
\end{pmatrix}$$so that$$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial u\partial v}=\begin{pmatrix}
\sum_k\frac{\partial^2f_1}{\partial x_k\partial x_1}u_k & \cdots & \sum_k\frac{\partial^2f_1}{\partial x_k\partial x_m}u_k\\
 \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\sum_k\frac{\partial^2f_n}{\partial x_k\partial x_1}u_k & \cdots & \sum_k\frac{\partial^2f_n}{\partial x_k\partial x_m}u_k
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
v_1\\
 \vdots \\
v_m
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\sum_{k,l}\frac{\partial^2f_1}{\partial x_k\partial x_l}u_kv_l\\
 \vdots \\
\sum_{k,l}\frac{\partial^2f_n}{\partial x_k\partial x_l}u_kv_l
\end{pmatrix}$$and$$\left\|\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial u\partial v}(x)\right\|\leq\max_i\sum_{k,l}\left|\frac{\partial^2f_i}{\partial x_k\partial x_l}(x)\right||u_k||v_l|\leq\max_i\sum_{k,l}\left|\frac{\partial^2f_i}{\partial x_k\partial x_l}(x)\right|\|u\|\|v\|.$$

Comment: Perhaps I don't see it but you still need to take out from the inequality $\max_i  \sum (...)$